# How do I plot curves of a sequence of functions indexed by i

Tags: matlab, function, math

I was trying to plot the graphs in the interval [60, 110] of a sequence of ten functions `f_i(t)` in the same figure, whose definitions will be clear from the code below:

```
figure
i=1;
while i<=10;
    P_i=abs(sin(i));
    r_i=0.005*abs(cos(i.^2));
    y=@(i,t)P_i*exp(r_i*t)/(1+P_i*(exp(r_i*t)-1));
    % disp([(y(i,67));(y(i,68));(y(i,69))]');
    s=linspace(60,110,51);


        i=i+1;
    continue;
end;
```

I ran the piece of code and it works. As you see, I could create one single function `y(i,t)` where `i` is an integer `1<=i<=10`, and `t` is a continuous variable. But how can I construct ten functions `y_i` of a single variable `t` in the above code and plot their graphs in the same figure, so it'll consist of the graphs of ten functions together. How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried: figure  hold on?

Comment: Okay, I've done so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all some minor modifications on your code. `P_i` and `r_i` are functions as well, so define them as functions. This way you only need to define the function once. Besides using a loop as you did it easily causes errors. `i` is the imaginary unit and you did not initialise it. Use a `for` loop instead and avoid `i`

```
P_i=@(i)abs(sin(i));
r_i=@(i)0.005*abs(cos(i.^2));
k=1:10;
t=60:101;
y=@(i,t)P_i(i)*exp(r_i(i)*t)/(1+P_i(i)*(exp(r_i(i)*t)-1));
```

To plot a Matrix with all values is required:

```
M=nan(numel(ik),numel(it));
for ik=1:numel(k)
    for it=1:numel(t)
        M(ik,it)=y(k(kx),t(it));
    end
end
```

And finally Plot it. I did not really understand if you want `plot(k,M)` or `plot(t,M)` but one should be the right.